# DbUpdateException in MVC Controller when I try to edit database entry

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Here is my edit action method:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include ="ID,Title,Issue,CreationDate,Status,Priority,UserID")] Ticket ticket)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {              
        db.Entry(ticket).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    ViewBag.UserID = new SelectList(db.Users, "Id", "UserName", ticket.UserID);
    return View(ticket);
}
```

A `System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException` occurs every time at `db.SaveChanges()`. My create action method is very similar but works fine.

I have another table in my db called Updates which has a foreign key `TicketID` linking it to a Ticket. Each Ticket can have multiple Updates. I think this may be what's causing the issue but I'm not sure how to fix it as I'm quiet new to mvc.

Comment: The DbUpdateException is caused by mostly database constraint violations. Show us the error message so we pinpoint the exact violation.

Comment: Why do you have an extra comma at the end of the list of properties you include during model binding? Does that cause the problem?

Comment: No that extra comma shouldn't be there but I have removed it now and it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: I'm just getting a System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException. How do I view the inner exception?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make break point to your method and there you inspect this object and its parameters that controller edit method receive. It may be problem that you are not passing all needed parameters from your view to controller. Check that first.